# Doesn't enter in the "for-loop"?

Tags: java, for-loop

Here is my code :

```
private String SerialNo;
private String FirmVersion;


public String  GetSerial(int[] Data){

    System.out.println("GetSerial Debug : Data => "+Data);

    for (int i = 2;i==13;i++){
        System.out.println("In the FOR => ok ");
        if (i != 9){
            SerialNo = SerialNo + Data[i];  
        }
        if (i == 9){
            SerialNo = SerialNo + ".";
        }
    }

    System.out.println("SerialNo => "+ SerialNo);
    return SerialNo;
}
```

My problem : I can't "enter" in the FOR

So my sysout of "In the FOR => ok", never shows and all the "actions" aren't done.

What am I doing wrong ?

ps : I'm sure that I'm compiling the right file.

Comment: You initialise `i=2`, that say it has to equal 13 to enter the loop. So of course you're not going to enter the loop.

Comment: ok, sry my bad i tought that the second argument was the exit condition but i think i just expressed it wrongly.

Comment: No, it's the `enter and stay in loop while...` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examine your for statement:

`for (int i = 2; i==13; i++)`

This actually means the following:

1. assign `2` to `i`
2. Check whether `i` equal to `13`. If yes, continue loop, exit otherwise.

Since i is not 13 in the first iteration of loop you never enter it. I believe that you wanted to write

`for (int i = 2; i <= 13; i++)`

In this case you will iterate from 2 to 13 inclusively. The condition of for loop means "do I have to remain iterating?" and not "do I have to escape?"

Answer (score 4):

The loop condition is never satisfied; `i = 2` in the begin, the first check would fail, so all the loop would fail. Maybe it should be changed for:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 13; ++i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `for (int i = 2; i == 13; i++)` to `for (int i = 2; i <= 13; i++)`.

The second argument is the loop condition which has to be true to run the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition became false at first iteration so control never goes to loop body.

for loop syntax:

```
for(initialization; condition; increment/ decrement){
  //your code
}
```

So here you will have to use some appropriate condition to enter into the loop.

So for example :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 13; i++) // for 0 to 13 increment
```

or

`for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--) // for 10 to 0 decrement`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 2;i==13;i++){}
```

It enters but failed at first condition check and `for-loop` exits.

It should be -

```
for (int i = 2;i<=13;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized `i=2`

```
 for (int i = 2;i==13;i++)
```

And condition is `i==13` which will become `false` ultimately flow never enter into for loop

try to change the code like this

```
for (int i = 2;i<=13;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Statement is not good should be like the one below:

for (int i = 2; i<13; i++) or for (int i = 2; i<=13; i++)

Answer (score 0):

See compared simple `while loop` in the case of your `for` loop.

Think about `int i =2;` value set and `i == 13` condition

1. Do you think it will work?

   ```
   for (int i = 2;i==13;i++){
     //do something
   }

   Same to below *while loop* explanation

   int i = 2;
   while (i == 13) {
       //do something
       i++;
   }
   ```
2. I am sure it will work

   ```
   for (int i = 2;i < 13;i++){
      //do something
   }

   Same to below **while loop**

   int i = 2;
   while (i < 13) {
       //do something
       i++;
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

The flow of the for loop is: init statement-> condition check-> goes inside loop or outside depending on the condition outcome.

Here, since you've said i=2 ,then i==13 is false; it'll never go inside the loop.
You could use the ?: operator in the for loop and then modify your if statements a bit I guess..

Comment: Do you have time to write "you have" instead of "uv" or are you in a hurry?